# Creat PDF of UITableView within UIView so all rows print

Tags: iphone, ipad, printing

I have a UIView holding many things including a UITableView at the bottom. I need to print this page and have all rows show in the final product but I run into problems with rows that are not currently visible in the TableView.

My current attempt to get a final product is to convert my view to a PDF and I have ready Apple's Drawing and Printing guide but it does not give me all the steps I need.

How can I print a UIView and have all the TableView rows, within the UIView, show in the print?

Answer (score 0):

Try the contentSize method, which is inherited from UITableView’s superclass, UIScrollView. However, you may find that contentSize returns an incorrect or out of date value, so you should probably call layoutIfNeeded first to recalculate the table’s layout.

```
 [tableView layoutIfNeeded];
```

// Allows you to perform layout before the drawing cycle happens. 
//-layoutIfNeeded forces layout early. So it will correctly return the size. Like dreaming before doing.

```
CGSize newTableSize=tableView.contentSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSMutableData*)generatePDF {

    NSMutableData * pdfData=[NSMutableData data];

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PDFView" owner:self options:nil];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero,nil);
    CGContextRef pdfContext=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

   //  update the UI elements (IBOutlet on xib file)


   //PDFView is main view on xib file containing uitableview too 

    [self.PDFView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext]; 

    //  end PDF context.

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    return pdfData;
}
```